# How do i import a list from another file and "gather" data from it? (Python)

Tags: python

First of all, i'd like to point out that I'm an extreme beginner, as Python is the first programming language I ever tried to learn. So i was creating this script that would read a list (x) in another file (name.py), randomly pick a word out of it, then print it out. The code is as follows :

```
import tkinter
import random

def pickName():
    exec(open("name.py").read())
    limit = len(x)
    result = int(random.randrange(limit))  
    finalResult = x.pop(result)
    print ("Your lucky word is: %s ." %finalResult)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Arcadia")
root.geometry("200x100")

finalResult = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 32))
finalResult.pack()

pickButton = tkinter.Button(text="Generate", command=pickName)
pickButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have the name.py in the same directory as the main script, yet it says that "x" in len(x) is not defined, x being the name of the list that is in name.py.
My code used to work in versions 2.7x or so, but now I updated to 3.4 and I had to change a few things such as the exec command, and now it just doesn't work... Can someone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: You need to import it. `from name import x`

Comment: forget about `exec`. Please. There's almost no reason to use `exec`. It's a security hole waiting to happen. I'm not saying that it doesn't have its place in the language, but, honestly, until you can honestly describe yourself as "not a beginner", do not touch `exec`, `execfile`, or `eval`. Just leave the dangerous toys alone for now :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get at a list defined in another file, you would `import` it

```
from name import x
```

or

```
import name
# then use name.x
```